# Template fails if JSON property names contains full stop

Tags: javascript, json, jsrender

I'm using jsRender to render templates, however my JSON data property names contain full stops.

Taking a simple example online this works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/mythical/4rtTy/

With a full stop in the property name, it no longer works:

http://jsfiddle.net/zLbw8rLL/

What syntax / technique do I need to use to allow jsRender to fetch these properties?

```
var data = {
    people: [{
        "full.name": 'Dan Wahlin',
        shirtColor: 'white'
    }]
};


{{for people}}
<li>{{:full.name}} likes to wear {{:shirtColor}} shirts</li>
{{/for}}
```

Comment: name is a property of full when you namespace it like that. "Full" would have to be an object of its own using your syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as in Javascript you can write `data.key` or `data['key']`, you can actually get JsRender to access property names like `"full.name"` by using the syntax `#data['someKey']` - since `#data` is the current data item.

So in your case you can write:

```
{{for people}}
    <li>{{:#data['full.name']}} likes to wear {{:shirtColor}} shirts</li>
{{/for}}
```

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/zLbw8rLL/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have this JSON:

```
var data = {
    people: [{
        "full.name": 'Dan Wahlin',
        shirtColor: 'white'
    }]
};
```

And this Template

```
{{for people}}
<li>{{:full.name}} likes to wear {{:shirtColor}} shirts</li>
{{/for}}
```

This is incorrect, because jsRender try get values on this json structure:

```
var data = {
    people: [
        {
        "full": { "name":'Dan Wahlin'},
        shirtColor: 'white'},
    {
        "full": { "name":'John Papa' },
        shirtColor: 'black'},
    {
        "full": { name: 'Scott Guthrie'},
        shirtColor: 'red'}
    ]
};
```

Reference: https://www.jsviews.com/#assigntag
Sample: {{:data.paths}}